# Parameter passing through javascript function to a servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

Can we pass parameter to a servlet through javascript function?

Here is my code wherein i am trying to pass values from addUpdate.jsp's javascript function to BookServlet on click of a button 'Get Authors names'.While I click the button it is successfully going to servlet but it does not taking the parameter that I pass through function..

addUpdate.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page import="com.fulcrum.obl.model.Author"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitAddForm(button) {
    alert("hiee");
    if(button.value=="Get Authors names") {
        alert("in iff");
        //alert(document.getElementById("bookDetails"));
        document.getElementById("bookDetails").action="BookServlet?authorNames=authorNames";
    }

}

function setAuthorsNames() {

     var x =document.getElementById("select");
     var myList = document.getElementById("selected");
     var myOption = document.createElement("Option");

    for(var i=0;i < x.options.length;i++) {

         if(x.options[i].selected ==true){
             alert("in if");
              myOption.text = x.options[i].value;
              myOption.value = x.options[i].value;
              myList.add(myOption);
              x.remove(x.options.selectedIndex);

          }

    }

}




</script>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Book Form</h4>

<form  id="bookDetails">
Long Title : <input type="text" name="longT">
<br>
<br>
Short Title : <input type="text" name="shortT" />
<br>
<br>
Isbn :  <input type="text" name="shortT" />
<br>
<br>
Date of Publication : <input type="text" name="dop" />
<br>
<br>
No of pages : <input type="text" name="nop" />
<br>
<br>
bound type : 
<select id="boundType">
  <option value="0">HardBound</option>
  <option value="1">SoftBound</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
DVD Availability :

<select id="dvd">
  <option value="y">Yes</option>
  <option value="n">No</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
No of copies available :  <input type="text" name="noca" />
<br>
<br>
<% 
if(request.getAttribute("authorNamesList") != null) {

    ArrayList<Author> booksList = (ArrayList<Author>)request.getAttribute("authorNamesList");
%>

<select id="select" size="6">
 <c:forEach items="${authorNamesList}" var="authorNames">
<option value="${authorNames.firstName}">${authorNames.firstName}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
<%
}
%>
<select size="6"  id="selected">

</select>

<input type="submit" value="Get Authors names" name="Go" onClick="submitAddForm(this)">
<input type="button" value="Add" name="Add" onClick="setAuthorsNames()">
<br>
<br>

<input type="submit" value="Save Book" name="submitBook" onClick="submitAddForm()">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the parameter that is getting passed..

```
http://localhost:8082/OBL/BookServlet?longT=&shortT=&shortT=&dop=&nop=&noca=&Go=Get+Authors+names
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden input element and set the value of the hidden input element before submitting the form.

Lets say your hidden element has id "hidden_input" then in your submitAddForm function add the following line

```
document.getElementById("hidden_input").value = "desired_value";
```

now when form is submitted ... the hidden input value will be set and passed to the server

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code and pass the parameters from javascript to the servlets by using :-

```
function submitAddForm(button) {


     var longT = document.getElementById("bookDetails").value;
     var shortT = document.getElementById("shortT").value;
     ...........
     ........... 
     then pass the variables and do 

     document.forms[0].action = "BookServlet?longT="+longT+"shortT="+shortT....and all the other variables to pass;     
     document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

And in your JSP you can have an "id" attribute as :

Long Title : `<input type="text" name="longT" id="longT">`